# Assigning value from tuple to one variable in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not entirely sure what this is called, so I was having a hard time googling it.

I have a collection of custom objects:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class MatchMode:
    name: str
    description: str
    players: int
```

These objects are instantiated in my main class:

```
MATCH_MODES = (
    MatchMode("Name1", "Description1", 2), 
    MatchMode("Name2", "Desc2", 4)
)
```

I'm pulling all of the name's from each `MatchMode` into another variable like this:

```
self.matches_queue = {x.name.lower(): [] for x in self.MATCH_MODES}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is pull a subset of them into a variable in one line:

```
self.matches_queue = {x.name.lower(): [] for x in //self.MATCH_MODES where Players = 2//}
```

The problem I'm currently having is I dont know what this is called in order to google how to syntax

```
things: variable = {x.name.lower(): [] for x in self.MATCH_MODES}
```

Also, within this function, am I able to put some sort of filtering to only pull `MATCH_MODES` where `Players = 2`?

Edit: I ended up just solving it with this. it would be nice to have a more elegant solution:

```
        for modes in self.MATCH_MODES:
            if modes.players == 2:
                self.two_player_formats[modes.name.lower()] = []
```

Comment: `{x.name.lower(): [] for x in self.MATCH_MODES}` is called a dictionary comprehension (or dictionary display).

Comment: what is inelegant about your solution? It is perfectly pythonic.